# Aligning dynamically created buttons vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to make a page for stuff, and I'm at a decent stage. I hit a roadblock on, of all things, trying to vertically align buttons I create using javascript in the document.

I've tried numerous things like throwing display style: block; just about everywhere I can, but the buttons simply refuse to work with me.

I was able to make a function where the buttons would be built into a list instead, but because they lost the outlook of buttons (though they still functioned like they had to) I decided to scrap the solution.

For some reason JSFiddle doesn't show the buttons, but here's the code I'm running and trying to work with.

https://jsfiddle.net/jets29sy/8/

```js
var URLobj = {
  linkname1: "https://stackoverflow.com/",
  linkname2: "https://www.google.com",
  linkname3: "https://en.wikipedia.org/"
};

function exitbutton() {
  var textelement = document.getElementById("text");
  textelement.style.display = "block";

  var buttonelement = document.getElementById("buttons");
  buttonelement.style.display = "block";

  var headerelement = document.getElementById("header");
  buttonelement.style.display = "block";

  var iframe = document.getElementById("iframeID");
  iframe.src = "#";
  iframe.style.display = "none";

  var exitbutton = document.getElementById("buttonID");
  exitbutton.style.display = "none";
}

function iframeLoaded() {
  var iframeID = document.getElementById("iframeID");
  iFrameID.height = 0;
  iFrameID.width = 0;

} // add to game // parent.iframeLoaded();

function add(name, URL) {
  var element = document.createElement("button");

  //Assign different attributes to the element.
  element.setAttribute("value", URL);
  element.setAttribute("id", "gamebutton");
  element.innerHTML = name;
  element.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("iframeID").src = this.getAttribute("value");
    document.getElementById("iframeID").width = "95%";
    document.getElementById("iframeID").height = "95%";
    document.getElementById("iframeID").style.display = "block";

    var exitbuttonelement = document.getElementById("buttonID");
    exitbuttonelement.style.display = "block";

    var textelement = document.getElementById("text");
    textelement.style.display = "none";

    var buttonelement = document.getElementById("buttons");
    buttonelement.style.display = "none";

    var headerelement = document.getElementById("header");
    buttonelement.style.display = "none";
  };

  var foo = document.getElementById("foobar");

  //Append the element in page (in span).
  foo.appendChild(element);
}

window.onload = function() {
  for (var key in URLobj) {
    if (URLobj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      add(key, URLobj[key])
    }
  }
};
```

```css
#buttons {
  vertical-align: right;
  float: right;
  display: block;
}

#foobar {
  display: block;
}

#text {
  vertical-align: right;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

#buttonID {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<head scroll="no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="page.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="page.js"></script>
</head>
<body scroll="no">
  <div id="header" , style="block">
    <h2>Your links are located here.</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="buttons" , style="display: block">
    <span id="foobar" style="block">&nbsp;</span><br/>
  </div>
  <div id="exit"><button type="button" id="buttonID" style="display: none" onclick=exitbutton()>Exit link!</button></div>
  <div class="frame_div" , background-color="blue">
    <iframe id="iframeID" , width="0" , height="0" , align="middle"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="text" , id="text" , style="block">
    <tr>
      <th>Choose your link from the list.<br></th>
    </tr>
  </div>
</body>
```

When I run it locally, I do see everything I need to see, but my buttons are aligned horizontally instead. The location of the buttons div isn't so important now, all I want to figure out is how I can align the buttons vertically in the  I'm storing them in, either by using javascript, html or css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about :

```css
#foobar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
}
```

Comment: This does the job! Any idea why block would not do its job here?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add inside of `div` tag no need to extra tag `span` inside of `div`(**buttons**) and add `css` for button `display: block;`.

**DEMO**

```js
var URLobj = {
  linkname1: "https://stackoverflow.com/",
  linkname2: "https://www.google.com",
  linkname3: "https://en.wikipedia.org/"
};

function exitbutton(){

 var textelement = document.getElementById("text");
 textelement.style.display = "block";
 
 var buttonelement = document.getElementById("buttons");
 buttonelement.style.display = "block";
 
 var headerelement = document.getElementById("header");
 buttonelement.style.display = "block";
 
 var iframe = document.getElementById("iframeID");
 iframe.src = "#";
 iframe.style.display = "none";
 
 var exitbutton = document.getElementById("buttonID");
 exitbutton.style.display = "none";
 
}

function iframeLoaded(){
 var iframeID = document.getElementById("iframeID");
 iFrameID.height = 0;
 iFrameID.width = 0;

} // add to game // parent.iframeLoaded();


function add(name, URL) {
  var element = document.createElement("button");

  //Assign different attributes to the element.
  element.setAttribute("value", URL);
  element.innerHTML = name;
  element.onclick = function () {
   document.getElementById("iframeID").src = this.getAttribute("value");
 document.getElementById("iframeID").width = "95%";
 document.getElementById("iframeID").height = "95%";
 document.getElementById("iframeID").style.display = "block";
 
 var exitbuttonelement = document.getElementById("buttonID");
 exitbuttonelement.style.display = "block";
 
 var textelement = document.getElementById("text");
 textelement.style.display = "none";
 
 var buttonelement = document.getElementById("buttons");
 buttonelement.style.display = "none";
 
 var headerelement = document.getElementById("header");
 buttonelement.style.display = "none";
  };

  var foo = document.getElementById("buttons");

  //Append the element in page (in span).
  foo.appendChild(element);
}

window.onload = function() {
  for (var key in URLobj) {
    if (URLobj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      add(key, URLobj[key])
    }
  }
};
```

```css
#buttons {
 vertical-align: right;
 float: right;
 display: block;
 
}
#foobar {
 display: block;
}
#text {
 vertical-align: right;
 float: left;
 text-align: left;
}

#buttonID {
 float: right;
}

.btn-group button {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<head scroll="no">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="page.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="page.js"></script>
</head>
<body scroll="no">
 <div id="header", style="block"><h2>Your links are located here.</h2></div>
 <div class="btn-group" id="buttons"></div>
 <div id="exit"><button type="button" id="buttonID" style = "display: none" onclick=exitbutton()>Exit link!</button></div>
 <div class = "frame_div", background-color="blue">
    <iframe id="iframeID", width="0", height="0", align="middle"></iframe>
  </div>
 <div class = "text", id="text", style="block">
 <tr>
  <th>Choose your link from the list.<br></th>
 </tr>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: block` should have solved your problem.

The problem I see with your code is that you added it to the wrong place. You added the style to the `<div id="buttons">` but not the individual `<button>` items in the div

[image: no style]

Adding the style to those elements will give your desired result

[image: with style]

Comment: I see, this clears up a lot of what I was doing wrong. Thanks!